# Global Hotkeys Dont Work When App-Specific Menu is Expanded

Tags: shortcut-keys

This is a pretty precise issue that I dont see covered anywhere. Steps to reproduce:

1. Verify that shortcut works (lets use Super+L to lock Ubuntu for this example)
2. Do one of the following:

   - Right click in the browser to open a context menu
   - Open an app-specific menu (in Google Chrome, the settings hamburger menu, in IntelliJ, any of the IntelliJ menus, etc. This will *not* happen with an Ubuntu native menu, like the File, Editor, View, etc. menus that every app has)
3. While app-specific menu is open, attempt to lock Ubuntu with Super+L
4. Ubuntu doesnt lock

This is happening with every app Ive tried so far, and with every global shortcut ive tried that does something to the window (media keys still seem to work, for example, but other ones, like my custom hotkey that activates `gnome-screenshot -ca`, dont work).

Any ideas?

Im currently using 17.04, though Im pretty sure this is happening on 16.04 as well. Will confirm when I can.

Edit: Confirmed with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as well

Comment: Isn't this is a [well-known shortcoming](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347337/70524) of the X11 windowing system? I don't know how the global menu works around it, but IIRC Wayland doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @muru How does one switch to this mysterious Wayland? Im seeing a lot of talk about the fact that it is, or will be, supported, but not so much information on how to actually use it, and the Ubuntu help page on Wayland is marked as outdated

Comment: Even still, Im not sure that its really a solution, as it seems that nVidia drivers dont support it...?